# CakePHP How to call command that was calling from different file before?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm again lost with CakePHP.

Before site was using "static" one page invite for users from twitter, and now, I want all of those on one page.
I menage to create it for Facebook, but I can't for twitter.

I find controller file, it's the same for both, routes.php is redirecting on same way for both, I find file that is rendering in this command, but when I try to use:

```
$this->renderElement('fetch_twitter_contact');
```

It get's it all wrong.
And if it's called from original file it's all working okay.

I checked original file and it doesn't have anything different than this new have ( no special commands in front ), but still something is different.

Can someone tell me what else is deciding which codes will be run if file name is different?

How can I turn same functions to work in new file like it was working in old one?

New file have name index.ctp, and old one had social_contacts.ctp

New link is friend_invites/ and old one had friend_invites/social_contacts ( or friend_invites/social_contacts?contect=twitter )

It's 6AM here, and I'm still busting me head off with this.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very difficult to understand. I suggest you get some sleep and clean up the question a bit so we can help :)

From what I understand, you're trying to call `fetch_twitter_contact` from two different views, but it only work from 1 view? Is this the problem?

Please go through this list and update your question

1. Have you set `debug` to `2` in core.php? If not, please do it
2. Are you getting any error messages? Post them in this question
3. Where is the element stored? In the `elements` folder or in a different folder inside the `view` folder?
4. `It get's it all wrong`. What does this mean? What goes wrong? What do you expect to happen?
5. Can you post the FULL url and associated views you are trying to use?